# What is the holiness status of a Siddur

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, prayer-book, priorities

The Shulhan Aruch (Y"D 282) tells us that one should stack certain books in a certain order (e.g. Humash on top of a Sefer Navi). What is the Din of a Siddur for this purpose?

My friend told me he asked a very famous Posek who said that a Sidur has the same status of e.g. a Sefer Musar. Today I was told that my Rosh Yeshiva holds that it has the status of Sefer Tehilim.

What do the sources have to say?

CYLOR

(I'm asking only according to the opinion that applies the stacking rules of the Gemara/Shulchan Aruch to printed and bound books.)

Comment: Meaning excluding the Aruch Hashulchan's opinion

Comment: @sam ...and those who hold like him.

Comment: Who holds that the stacking rules still apply to bound ספרים?

Comment: Interesting, I, too, thought that it was supposed to go on the bottom. That is, with the mussar

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/megilah/halachah/mg-hl-027.htm):

> Ha'Gaon R. S.Z. Auerbach said that the Aruch ha'Shulchan's opinion was not accepted. He and ha'Gaon R. N. M. Karelitz, Shlita hold that a Sidur has Kedushah like Nevi'im or Kesuvim. Ha'Gaon R. C. Kanievsky, Shlita equates its Kedushah to that of a Gemara. Ha'Gaon R. Y.S. Elyashiv, Shlita agrees, but advises not to put a Sidur on top of Seforim, or vice-versa (Ginzei ha'Kodesh 3:30, p.232).